# LTSpice: Why are my capacitors half charged at simulation start?

Tags: ltspice, capacitor-charging

This is my first time using LTSpice, and I am trying to simulate what should be a very simple RC circuit ladder. I've gone ahead and set the initial state of each capacitor to zero using the .IC directive. However, when I simulate, the capacitors already hold half the value of the voltage source. What am I doing wrong? I've included a screenshot showing the circuit and transient simulation output (voltage of all capacitors and source current across resistor R1).

[image: circuit and simulation output]

Edit:  With "startup" added to the .tran directive, I get this:

[image: With "startup" added]

Comment: I have jus one doubt, the initial conditions defined by u are wrt ground. What i believe is the IC u want to set is for the Caps.

Comment: How would I do that? And I've also set the initial voltage of the node below the caps to zero too, at least for the first few. It doesn't seem to change the result.

Comment: @user15713  I don't believe it solves your problem, but what he's referring to is you can set a capacitor's initial condition after its capacitance value, something like: `1n ic=0` (see the [help section for capacitors](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/C_Capacitor.htm)).  If you do this you also have to use the `uic` flag in the `.tran` command, which is the same as checking the "Skip initial operating point solution" checkbox.

Comment: What does ["doubt" mean](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question) here?

Comment: IC what? The LTSpice directive? Capacitor current?

Answer (score 8):

> Why are my capacitors half charged at simulation start?

They are not. You are not measuring the voltage across the capacitors. You measured the voltage at the top nodes, related to 0V.

To measure the voltages across the capacitors, you should click in one terminal, hold and release over the other terminal (your OS may vary, maybe you have to click over the second one).

At the start time, \$VC1=VCG1=500V\$. So, all the other nodes are at the same potential.

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely at the left edge of the waveform you will see a blue vertical line, that is the voltage going from the initial condition you have set of 0 V to 500 V. The 500 V is because with both sides of the capacitors set to 0 V they appear as a short, so R1 and R2 form a voltage divider and you are measuring from the center of them (VC1) to ground. Each successive node that you measure, VC2, VC3, etc., also show 500 V right after the initial condition because with the capacitors acting like short circuits it's like having a string of 5K resistors with no connection at the end.

So VC1 is initialized to 0 V and then almost instantly you have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ2MmX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each VCx point will be 500 V, then as the capacitors charge those voltages will rise.

As others have said, this is what you will see when you measure from VC1, VC2, VC3, etc., to ground, you need to set the reference point to the other side of the caps to measure the voltage across them.

Answer (score 3):

It's just the voltage division from the resistors to source. That's why the last caps also charge slower.